# What can you do with octonions?

Tags: division-algebras, octonions

How can you calculate with them and what can you actually make up from the calculations? And what is exactly meant by normed division-algebras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your second question, a normed division algebra is $A$ is an algebra over a field which has a sub-multiplicative norm:
$$\forall x,y\in A\qquad \|xy\|\le\|x\|\|y\|$$

The interesting thing about octonions is that they form the highest dimensional normed division algebra over the reals (up to an isomorphism): see Hurwitz's theorem.

**References:** *"Normed Algebra". Encyclopaedia of Mathematics. Retrieved 6 June 2013.*

**Edit**: For your first question, I suggest you check out [What are some real-world uses of Octonions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-are-some-real-world-uses-of-octonions).

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested at all in representation theory, the octonion algebra is the setting for a representation of the smallest exceptional Lie group.